# C Convert to Farhenheit Convert to Celsius

Tags: c

I wrote up this quickly and every time I execute the program I always end up with 32 for fahrenheit and 0.00 for celsius and am not sure what the issue is here.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(void)
 {
     double celsius=0, fahrenheit=0;
     printf("Enter a temperature in degrees Celsius: ");
     scanf("%f", &celsius);
     fahrenheit =(5.0/9.0)*celsius + 32;
     printf("That is %.2f Fahrenheit \n", fahrenheit);
     printf("Enter a temperature in degrees fahrenheit: ");
     scanf("%f", &fahrenheit);
     celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * (5.0/9.0);
     printf("That is %.2f Celsius \n", celsius);
     return(0);
 }
```

Comment: Most compilers warn about this now. _warning: format specifies type 'float *' but the argument has type 'double *' [-Wformat]_

Comment: On the `f` format, `scanf` requires `%f` for `float` and `%lf` for `double`, whereas `printf` requires `%f` for both.

Comment: A *very* minor point: the parentheses in `return(0);` are unnecessary. `return 0;` is simpler and clearer. (`return` is a statement, not a function call.)

Comment: Sorry I am taking C 101 and this is all new, but thanks for all the help and suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format specifier for `double` is wrong, it should be `"%lf"`. But that's not enough, you should also check that `scanf()` successfuly read read the value, like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int report_error(const char *const message)
{
    // TODO: add message formatting capabilities to this function
    fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", message);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

int main(void)
{
    double celsius = 0;
    double fahrenheit = 0;

    printf("Enter a temperature in degrees Celsius: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &celsius) != 1)
        return report_error("Invalid Input");
    fahrenheit = (5.0 / 9.0) * celsius + 32;
    //                ^ Define this as a constant?

    printf("That is %.2f Fahrenheit \n", fahrenheit);
    printf("Enter a temperature in degrees fahrenheit: ");

    if (scanf("%lf", &fahrenheit) != 1)
        return report_error("Invalid Input");
    celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * (5.0 / 9.0);
    //                                 ^ see if it was a constant???

    printf("That is %.2f Celsius \n", celsius);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, it appears that your algebra went wrong. You should check the `celsius` expression apparently.

Comment: Why are you doing a `return -1` in `main`? The only portable return values are `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `EXIT_FAILURE`. It would also be nice to print an error message rather than just dying.

Comment: @iharob deleted 'cos you already remarked on OP's error of `5.0 / 9.0` in C to F.

Comment: @KeithThompson Ok, is it better now?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It appears i was using celsius to fahrenheit for the f to c and it was the %lf that was wrong for the specifier